# How do I combine 2 DataFrames and add 2 column values together if both values exist or else return the non-null value instead if one is null?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Edit: I've realized that I did not ask my question in the right way. I'm not going to accept one answer over another, but am going to leave all content here for anyone's future use.

I have 2 DataFrames that I want to combine. I'd like to merge them only on the Name column so that all Name values from both DataFrames are included in the resulting DataFrame. I'm having trouble with null values, however. If an Inches value exists in both DataFrames, I'd like to add them together to be a result in df3. If an Inches value only exists in one of the two DataFrames, I'd like the non-null value chosen to be as the df3 Inches value.

ie. 'Silvers' in df1 + 'Silvers' in df2 = 14 for 'Silvers' in df3. Likewise: 'Merole' in df1 + 'Merole' in df2 = 6 for 'Merole' in df3. Or: 'Jones' in df1 + 'Jones' in df2 = 7 for 'Jones' in df3

I have df1:

```
Name    | Inches
---------------------
'Silvers'|   7
'Jones'  |   7
'Jackson'|   4
'Merole' |   NaN
'Kanoff' |   3
'Walker' |   1
'Smith'  |   8
```

And df2:

```
Name    | Inches
---------------------
'Vickers' |   7
'Lederman'|   7
'Silvers' |   7
'Jones'   |   NaN
'Merole'  |   6
'Wilde'   |   2
'Nichols' |   5
```

I want df3:

```
Name    | Inches
---------------------
'Vickers' |   7
'Lederman'|   7
'Silvers' |   14
'Jones'   |   7
'Merole'  |   6
'Wilde'   |   2
'Nichols' |   5
'Jackson' |   4
'Kanoff'  |   3
'Walker'  |   1
'Smith'   |   8
```

Additionally, how would this be possible if there was a 3rd column with all null values that I want to keep as null?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge both the dataframes and then add the columns.

**Code:**

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Silvers','Jackson','Jones'],'inches':[7,4,7]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Silvers','Merole','Jones'],'inches':[7,4,np.nan]})

df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name',how='outer')
df3.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df3['inches']=df3['inches_x'] + df3['inches_y']
df3.drop(columns=['inches_x','inches_y'],inplace=True)
```

df1:

```py
    name    inches
0   Silvers 7
1   Jackson 4
2   Jones   7
```

df2:

```py
    name    inches
0   Silvers 7.0
1   Merole  4.0
2   Jones   NaN
```

df3:

```py
    name    inches
0   Silvers 14.0
1   Jackson 4.0
2   Jones   7.0
3   Merole  4.0
```

**EDIT**

Editing based on OP comments -- 
I have created 2 new dataframes showcasing all the possible cases.

**New Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Silvers','Jackson','Jones','Gary','test'],'inches':[7,4,7,0,np.nan]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Silvers','Merole','Jones','Gary','test'],'inches':[7,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name',how='outer')
df4=df3.copy()             #Keeping a copy of df3 as we will modify it soon.
df3.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df3['inches']=df3['inches_x'] + df3['inches_y']
df3.drop(columns=['inches_x','inches_y'],inplace=True)

for i in range(0,len(df3['inches'])):
    if df3['inches'][i] == 0:
        if (df4['inches_x'][i] == 0) or (df4['inches_y'][i] == 0):
            continue
        else:
            df3['inches'].loc[i] = np.nan
```

**Output:**

df1:

```py
    name    inches
0   Silvers 7.0
1   Jackson 4.0
2   Jones   7.0
3   Gary    0.0
4   test    NaN
```

df2:

```py
    name    inches
0   Silvers 7.0
1   Merole  4.0
2   Jones   NaN
3   Gary    NaN
4   test    NaN
```

df3 (**final output**):

```py
    name    inches
0   Silvers 14.0
1   Jackson 4.0
2   Jones   7.0
3   Gary    0.0
4   test    NaN
5   Merole  4.0
```

df4 (which is an earlier copy of df3, which we use to check which should be 0 and which should be NaN):

```py
    name    inches_x    inches_y
0   Silvers 7.0         7.0
1   Jackson 4.0         NaN
2   Jones   7.0         NaN
3   Gary    0.0         NaN
4   test    NaN         NaN
5   Merole  NaN         4.0
```

Comment: Hypothetically, how would this be possible if there was a 3rd column with a null value that I want to keep a null value? I don't want .fillna(0) because the value shouldn't be 0, it should be NaN.

Comment: In python, `NaN + 7 = NaN`. This is why I converted it to `0` first. If you want to keep it as `NaN` itself, then after performing the addition, replace `0` to `NaN` using `df3['inches']=df3['inches'].replace(0,np.nan)`

Comment: What if one column value is NaN and the other is 0? That would replace NaN with 0 and both would be added to equal 0, but using replace would change the result value from 0 to NaN which is not what I'd want. I'd want 0.

Comment: Any arithmetic operation on NaN results in NaN. In your case, after merging and creating df3, keep a check to see if the values being added are NaN and 0. If they are, keep the value as 0. For other cases, convert NaN to 0 and perform the addition.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Gary. How would the check look?

Comment: @WillWild -- Check the edit portion, it should answer all your queries.

Comment: @WillWild please accept and upvite if my answer helped!

Comment: I've realized that I did not ask my question in the right way. I'm not going to accept one answer over another, but am going to leave all content here for anyone's future use.

Comment: @WillWild : I don't think you understand how SO works. If you accept an answer that worked for you, it tells others that the answer is verified and can be used. It's hard for others to go through all answers and figure out which will work for them. Moreover, the points gives people like me the motivation to keep answering!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Index` alignment with `DataFrame.add`. Setting `fill_value=0` will make the sums work if values exist in only one DataFrame.

```
df1.set_index('Name').add(df2.set_index('Name'), fill_value=0)

          Inches
Name            
Jackson      4.0
Jones        7.0
Kanoff       3.0
Lederman     7.0
Merole       6.0
Nichols      5.0
Silvers     14.0
Smith        8.0
Vickers      7.0
Walker       1.0
Wilde        2.0
```

---

#### `pd.concat` + `groupby`

Create one long DataFrame then sum within each name:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Name')['Inches'].sum()
```

Comment: Hypothetically, how would this be possible if there was a 3rd column with a null value that I want to keep a null value? I don't want .fillna(0) because the value shouldn't be 0, it should be NaN.

Comment: @WillWild then in that case I would go with the `concat` + `groupby` solution. It allows you to aggregate each column with different functions, so you'd do something like `.groupby('Name').agg({'Inches': 'sum', 'other_col': 'first'})`

Comment: Is there a way to call .agg and the 'sum' function on multiple columns?